# understanding csv DictReader, what it returns?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

no mind about result of csv.DictReader, so and no possibility to know, are csv params specified correctly.

i have input

```
Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sda               0.17        53.98         0.14         0.00   55111129     145632          0
sde               0.14        53.99         0.14         0.00   55118669     147152          0
sdg               0.17        53.99         0.14         0.00   55117853     147076          0
```

only just spaces are trimmed to one

and that way i want to load it

```
ios_e = csv.DictReader(' '.join(ios_r.stdout.split()), delimiter = ' ', fieldnames = {'Device', 'tps', 'kB_read/s' ,'kB_wrtn/s', 'kB_dscd/s', 'kB_read', 'kB_wrtn', 'kB_dscd'})
```

*without specifying fieldnames result is worse, but it should be got by first line? but not

and, for example, I want to work with my Dict:

```
for v in ios_e.reader:
    for d in v:
        print(d)
```

and have (there more)

```
D
e
v
i
c
e


t
p
```

what i did - you see, what i am shold expect - i don't now
I expected matrix-like object, becouse csv like it

what i am get and why?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader shows that the return value is a iterable of dicts (each row is a dict) (assuming `python >= 3.8`

Answer (score 1):

The `csv.DictReader` function expects a file object as its first argument, not a string. So, it always is used with normal file io.

for example,

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ', fieldnames = ['Device', 'tps', 'kB_read/s' ,'kB_wrtn/s', 'kB_dscd/s', 'kB_read', 'kB_wrtn', 'kB_dscd'])
```

And, you can iterate the `reader` (i.e., iterable of dicts) row by row.

```
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

The row variable contains dictionary-like object that you can easily access by key, for example, `row['Device']`.

Comment: `ios_r.stdout` looks like the stdout of a subprocess. The `csv` module works with any iterable, not just a file, although that's the most common use.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module expects the input to be an iterable containing lines of the CSV. `' '.join(ios_r.stdout.split())` is returning a single string (it simply collapses all the whitespace delimiters into single spaces). Iterating over a string returns loops over the characters, not the lines.

You should perform the `join` and `split` on each line, not the entire stdout at once.

```
ios_e = csv.DictReader(' '.join(line.split()) for line in ios_r.stdout, delimiter = ' ')
```

You won't need the `fieldnames` argument in this code, since it will get them from the first line.